# Explode elements in braces/curly brackets separated by comma and no space (e.g. {a,b})

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks somewhat like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'x', 'y'], 
                   'B': ['{c,d}', '{e,f,g}', '', '{}']})
```

I want to remove the braces/curly brackets and explode each of the elements into its own row. So it would look something like this in the end:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'x', 'y'], 
                   'B': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '', '']})
```

I have tried to first eliminate the curly brackets with

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[1:-1] #this works
```

then expand/explode the elements with

```
df.set_index('A').B.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index('A') #this doesn't work
```

I have tried more ways to fix the latter part. However, I think even if it works, the code still does a very inefficient job as it takes a bit long (~ 2mins) on my dataset of around 10k rows. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a combination of `apply` and `explode` functions:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b'], 
                   'B': ['{c,d}', '{e,f,g}']})
df["B"]  = df["B"].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))
df = df.explode("B", ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

```
[Out]:
   A  B
0  a  c
1  a  d
2  b  e
3  b  f
4  b  g
```

EDIT: Figured out the [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) has an `ignore_index` keyword that can be useful in this case.

Comment: is there any method that also works for null/blank rows as well? when running my code was throwing "TypeError: 'NAType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @KitKat99, do you mean something like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['{c,d}', '{e,f,g}', '{}']})`

Comment: yess! i have edited my example input code for the example so that it includes all possible cases

Comment: There's no need for the lambda `df.B.str[1:-1].str.split(",")` will work, and doesn't have issues with `pd.NA`

Comment: For a more robust solution, why not use `df['B'].str.strip('{}')` and avoid using indices entirely